# Webhook Error: Issue while integrating Github with Jenkins

Tags: webhooks

There was an error setting up your hook: Sorry, the URL host localhost is not supported because it isn't reachable over the public Internet. While adding webhook getting this error.

Answer (score 10):

You are using a local ip address.  If you run ipconfig or ifconfig, you see the "local" ip address.

Github needs your public ip address.  For example go to https://whatismyipaddress.com/ and it will show your public address.  If you're running Jenkins on localhost:8080, then Github needs http://myPublicIP:8080 as the url.  Then you have to forward the port 8080 on your router to the computer running Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Use a reverse proxy tool like ngrok to get a public url for your private ip. Refer - https://ngrok.com/download. The steps to get a public url are easy and self explanatory. Just follow the steps in the link. Then use this url, replacing your private url for the webhook payload in github.